# Do I need to put rel="canonical" in the original page?

Tags: seo, rel-canonical, canonical-url

To other pages, with the same content, I need to put `rel="canonical"` in the `link` tag to prevent duplication.

```
<link href="https://example.com/original-page.html" rel="canonical">
```

My question, do I need to also put `rel="canonical"` in the original (canonical) page?

Comment: @w3dk Hi, I know my English grammar not good. But can you explain why you put word "also" after the "to".

Comment: Actually, the way you had it before ("also to") was OK, although it does read better the other way round ("to also"). I wouldn't have edited it if that was the only thing. Although I see I missed something on the first line, "with same the content" - that is incorrect, it should read "with the same content" ("the" and "same" reversed).

Comment: @w3dk Okay thanks. I want to know and keep my grammar right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's highly recommended. Google will probably understand what you mean without it, but it's highly encouraged to add it to all pages with the same content including the canonical page itself.

Comment: Definitely yes :)

Comment: There is actually a good reason for adding a `rel="canonical"` to the original/canonical page itself. If it is accessible with query strings and/or additional path information (`PATH_INFO`). eg. `/original-page.html?foo=bar` or `/original-page.html/path/info`, then adding the `rel="canonical"` will resolve any issues that could arise if these pages start getting linked to.